# Drizzle ORM date conversion problem between Javascript and PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, orm, timezone, utc, drizzle

Prerequisite: my timezone is GMT+3

I have a model drizzle model

```
export const events = pgTable('events', {
    id: serial('id').primaryKey(),
    name: varchar('name', {length: 256}).notNull(),
    date: date('date').notNull(),
});
```

I've inserted a record to the database

```
# insert into events (name, date) values ('Foobar', '2023-03-30');
```

When I query it it shows correctly in the result relation

```
 id |  name   |    date
----+---------+------------
100 | Foobar  | 2023-03-30
```

Now if I run the following code

```
const foo = await db.query.events.findFirst({
    where: eq(events.id, 100),
});
console.log(foo.date);
```

I get

```
2023-03-30T00:00:00.000Z
```

But if I view the database via drizzle-kit Studio, it shows the date as

```
2023-03-29T21:00:00.000Z
```

AND, if I use the foo's date value in another query

```
await db.query.events.findFirst({
    where: lt(events.date, foo.date),
    orderBy: desc(races.date),
});
```

I get **the same record** as I already have in the foo, **not** the one with earlier date - probably due to the fact that my filter value is 2023-03-30 but the database sees it as 2023-03-29. My analysis is that the lt (less than) comparison compares apple's and orange's. But I don't understand why? What should I do to fix it?

Do I need to set the database's timezone to UTC, and if then how? Or is there some other way to solve this?

Comment: 1) Is the `date`(I would suggest using another name) field actually a `date` type in Postgres? 2) What `show timezone;` return in Postgres? **Add answers as text update to question**.

Comment: Yes the type of the field is `date` is PostgreSQL - and you are correct, the name could be something else. The `show timezone;` shows `Europe/Helsinki`. I changed it to UTC. I still see the -3 hours times in the drizzle kit and the lt query still returns the same entity.

Comment: Then Drizzle Studio/Kit is doing a conversion somewhere. 1) A `date` does not have a timezone: `select '2023-10-09'::date;  10/09/2023` 2) The value you show is a `datetime/timestamp` so there a CAST being applied.  You might want to crank up the logging in Postgres and see what is actually hitting the database.

Comment: Thanks, totally agree. The drizzle kit can be viewed via a browser and somehow it "adds" the timezone information (incorrectly?) to the dates, that indeed are `date` type in db. I'll check the db logs, and am willing to change the date type to string, if necessary. :)

Comment: A search here [Drizzle Issues](https://github.com/drizzle-team/drizzle-orm/issues) found multiple date/datetime issues. This one [Issue 971](https://github.com/drizzle-team/drizzle-orm/issues/971) looked particularly relevant if you are using node-postgres as it points at [node-postgres datetime types](https://node-postgres.com/features/types#date--timestamp--timestamptz)

Comment: So it seems. I think I found a solution in my scenario. Not quite sure what is happening, but the fix was to change the date column's definition to `date: date("date", {mode: "date"}).notNull()`, i.e. add the mode as "date". Then it started treating my comparison right. And if I tested correctly, changing the database timezone didn't change the behaviour. Thanks @AdrianKlaver.

Comment: I'm going to  say `{mode: "date"}` is overriding `node-postgres` behavior of *node-postgres converts DATE and TIMESTAMP columns into the local time of the node process set at process.env.TZ.*.

Comment: @Janne - If that worked, please supply it as an answer instead of just a comment.  Stack Overflow allows (and encourages) you to answer your own questions.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The fix was to change the date column's definition to

```
date: date("date", {mode: "date"}).notNull()
```

i.e. add the mode as

> "date"

Comment: this doesn't work for me, i still have the problem you described where when the Date is loaded out of the database, it incorrectly is a full timestamp with timezone, and it's adjusted based on my machine's timezone, so `2023-03-30` has become `2023-03-29T21:00:00.000Z`. Frustrating.